# Set request.session before we

Tags: python, django, session

I am now coding along with a course to build a eCommerce website.
When it comes to the cart part, it talked about the session.
Then I have below question:
In below code, why do we have to write this `request.session['cart_id'] = '12'`?
I can't see the point to set up the `cart_id` before we try to see if it exists.
If we set up in advance, it won't be None, then why do we need to do the if/else loop?
I just can't really realize what's the target of this part please anyone enlighten! Thank you really so much!

```
def cart_create(user=None):
    cart_obj = Cart.objects.create(user=None)
    return cart_obj


def cart_home(request):
    request.session['cart_id'] = '12'
    cart_id = request.session.get("cart_id",None)
    qs = Cart.objects.filter(id=cart_id)
    if qs.count()==1:
        cart_obj = qs.first()
        print('Card ID exist')
        print(request.session.cart_id)
    else:
        cart_obj = cart_create()
        request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj.id
        print('New Cart ID created')
        print(request.session.cart_id)

    return render(request,"carts/home.html",{})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ## When sessions are saved
>
> By default, Django only saves to the session database when the session has been modified – that is if any of its dictionary values have been assigned or deleted:

So reading that, I can see they're modifying the session to save it to the database and then proceeding with the rest of the logic for handling the cart.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/

> To change this default behavior, set the SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST setting to True. When set to True, Django will save the session to the database on every single request.